# how to fix a conversational java program

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I'm having trouble understanding why my code doesn't work. I think there is something wrong with the syntax but I'm not sure what it is. Below is a very short hand of my code.

**also, how do I have a general response if none of the user answers match my predicted values?**

```
public class {

    public static void main (String[] args)  
    { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    

        System.out.println("Hello! My name is Computer. What's your name?");

        String name;
        name = sc.next(); 

        System.out.println("Hi," + name + "nice to meet you! What is your favorite color?");

        String color;
        color = sc.next();

        if (color.equalsIgnoreCase('blue')) {System.out.println("That's my favorite color too!");
    }


    } // main method
```

Comment: And, what's the problem?

Comment: how do I have a general response if none of the user answers match my predicted values?

Comment: First, I wouldn't keep modifying the question unless you're adding to it, now, none of the answers make sense.  I would have considered asking another question, but, basically you would need a final `else` statement which handled this eventuality...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String#equalsIgnoreCase` takes a `String`.  Single quotes denote a character, which should be a single character long.  Having said, this makes...

```
color.equalsIgnoreCase('blue')
```

Invalid.  It should be more like...

```
color.equalsIgnoreCase("blue")
```

And if I was been picky...

```
"blue".equalsIgnoreCase(color)
```

But that might be a little over kill just now...

When you try and ask the next question...

```
    }
    return 0;

}
System.out.println ("What's your favorite sport?");
```

You've started adding content outside of the context of the `main` method.  Generally code should be included within methods and static blocks.  Remove the `}` before the `System.out.println ("What's your favorite sport?");` and the `return 0;` statement

And basically, this repeats for the third and fourth questions.

This may mean you will need to add a `}` at the end of the file as well...

Comment: thank you! there is an error in the code still though. but I do see what you mean about String though, I should have caught that.

Comment: @kenwoodjen There are lots of errors, you need to remove each `return 0;` and trailing `}` before it will come close to been compilable.  See updates

Comment: @kenwoodjen your curly brackets aren't matching...

Answer (score 0):

You have a return statement in the middle of your code

```
       else if (color.equalsIgnoreCase('yellow')) {

        System.out.println("That's my favorite color too! Like the warm, shining sun!");
    }return 0;
}
```

Remove the `return 0` part and the `}`. You have half of your program outside of the `main()` block

Also, change your have all your strings between single quotes `'blue'`. You should change all of them to double quotes `"blue"`

**EDIT:**

Even after you edited the code you are still not aligning all of your curly braces.

Change:

```
    return 0; // YOU DONT NEED THIS PART
} // YOU MAIN ENDS HERE
        System.out.println("Well," + name + "I have to run. You sound like a great person. We'd get along very well! Take care.");


    sc.close();
} // main method
```

To:

```
      System.out.println("Well," + name + "I have to run. You sound like a great person. We'd get along very well! Take care.");
    sc.close();
} // YOU MAIN ENDS HERE
```

Comment: @kenwoodjen `void` methods don't return anything, that's the point...

Comment: @kenwoodjen you should use shortcuts for formatting code to make things easy for you. On Windows use: `CTRL+SHIFT+F` on Mac use `COMMAND+SHIFT+F`